# component not working in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am a beginner in joomla and php. I am making a openchat application in joomla.

Directory structure I have created is like:
com_openchat/administrator/components/com_openchat

I just want to enable the controller working in my code which is not happening.
Files related to this are:

controller.php
This defines the controller class as below:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die("Access Deny");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
jimport('legacy.controller.legacy');
class OpenChatController extends JControllerLegacy{
    function display(){
        JToolBarHelper::Title('Default');
        echo JText::_('COM_OPENCHAT');
    }
    function history(){
        echo "Chat history";
    }
    function blocked_user(){
        JToolBarHelper::Title('BLOCKED USERS');
        echo JText::_('COM_OPENCHAT_BLOCKED'); 
        echo "Welcome to list viaJcontoller";   
    }
}
?>
```

myopenchat.php
This executes the instance of the controller as below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
defined('_JEXEC') or die("Access Deny");
jimport('legacy.controller.legacy');
$controller=JControllerLegacy::getInstance('OpenChat');
$controller->execute(JRequest::getCmd('task'));
$controller->redirect();
?>
```

manifest.xml
It contains the code directory sturcture and placement of files

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
This file is used for writing all the extensions.
These files include the general installation information 
as well as parameters for the configuration of the extension itself.
-->
<extension type="component" version="3.4.5" method="upgrade">
  <name>com_openchat</name>
  <author>Manish Kumar</author>
  <version></version>
  <description>COM_OPENCHAT</description>
  <!--Include the media folder-->
  <media destination="com_openchat" folder="media">
    <folder>images</folder>
    <folder>css</folder>
    <folder>js</folder>
  </media>  
  <!--including the front end files-->
  <files folder ="components/com_openchat">
    <filename>myopenchat.php</filename>
    <filename>controller.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
  </files>
  <languages folder="language/en-GB">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.com_openchat.ini</language>
  </languages>
  <install>
    <sql>
      <file charset="utf8" driver="mysql">install.sql</file>
    </sql>
  </install>
  <update>
    <sql>
      <file charset="utf8" driver="mysql">update.sql</file>
    </sql>
  </update>
  <uninstall>
    <sql>
      <file charset="utf8" driver="mysql">uninstall.sql</file>
    </sql>
  </uninstall>
  <!--including the back end files-->
  <administration>
    <files folder ="administrator/components/com_openchat">
      <filename>myopenchat.php</filename>
      <filename>controller.php</filename>
      <filename>index.html</filename>
      <filename>install.sql</filename>
      <filename>update.sql</filename>
      <filename>uninstall.sql</filename>
    </files>
    <languages folder="administrator/language/en-GB">
      <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.com_openchat.ini</language>
      <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.com_openchat.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>    
    <menu link="option=com_openchat" img="media/images/chat_icon.png">COM_OPENCHAT</menu>
    <submenu>
      <menu link="option=com_openchat&amp;task=history" img="media/images/chat_history.png">COM_OPENCHAT_HISTORY</menu>
      <menu link="option=com_openchat&amp;task=blocked_user" img="media/images/blocked_user.png">COM_OPENCHAT_BLOCKED</menu>
    </submenu>
  </administration>
</extension>
```

In the backend of Joomla CMS when I click on Open Chat (Menu) -> Chat history (Sub Menu). This gives me an error 404 component not found.

Path to my github repository is
https://github.com/mkumar85/openchat_Joomla/tree/master/com_openchat/administrator/components/com_openchat

The issues seems the controller implemented is not working properly. But I could not debug it. Could you please let me know the coding issue here ?

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful. Add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: Done Editing to increase redability